# Is there any library to perform robust clustering given two probability distribution with noise?

Tags: python, clustering, statistics, k-means, parameter-estimation

Given a dataset $X$ consisted with $w|X|$ samples drawn from a mixture of multivariate Gaussian distributions (say in two dimensions) and $(1-w)|X|$ samples of noise, is there any `Python`, `Julia`, `Matlab`, `Mathematica` library that can perform a **robust parameter estimation for the Gaussians**?

Above, $|X|$ refers to the total number of elements of the two dimensional $(x,y)$ dataset $X$ and $0\ll w <1$. The idea is to readily use such a library such as to estimate means and covariances in the presence of noise (e.g. by disregarding from the estimation outliers).

Comment: as one can understand parameter estimation itself depends on $w$. In fact [gaussian estimation is robust in the presense of noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory), eg MLE method

Comment: No it is not. It depends on $w$ and only for very small $w$ it makes sense to use MLE. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02119.pdf and refs.